# c++, how to make a copy of the destination of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, copy

I have following code:

```
IMAGE *ptrInImage = ptrProcUnit->GetMeasureImage(0);
if (ptrInImage == NULL) {
    return(-2);
}
BYTE* rs, *rd, *rs2;
rs = (BYTE*)ptrInImage + sizeof(IMAGE);
rs2 = (BYTE*)ptrInImage + sizeof(IMAGE);
```

I would need rs2 to point to a exact copy of the destination of rs. Currently when I write data to the rs2 pointer, it is editing also the image that is behind rs. That is not what I need. I would need that rs2 points to an exact copy of rs, and that I write to that copy instead. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

The attempt that gave best results up to now was this, but it gave other problems like access errors.

```
IMAGE *ptrInImage = ptrProcUnit->GetMeasureImage(0);
if (ptrInImage == NULL) {
    return(-2);
}


IMAGE TmpImage;
IMAGE *ptrTmpImage = ptrProcUnit->GetImageData(0);
memcpy(ptrTmpImage, ptrInImage, sizeof(IMAGE));

BYTE* rs, *rd, *rs2;
rs = (BYTE*)ptrInImage + sizeof(IMAGE);
rs2 = (BYTE*)ptrTmpImage + sizeof(IMAGE);
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but you probably need to ***allocate memory*** for `rs2`, and copy the data into that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, the code was preexisting, except the "rs2" parts.. is there a way to make a copy of the value where the pointer points? so a copy of the actual image?

Comment: So you need to: (1) get some memory, (2) copy the data from memory you already have, into the new memory, and (3) make rs2 point to the new memory

Comment: @sharkyenergy memcpy will do that.

Comment: @user253751 thank you! i am already using memcopy.. but it is not working.. Shouldnt the line I wrote copy the source content of the image to the destination? I'm new to all this pointer world and its quite confusing...

Comment: The line you wrote copies a certain number of bytes from where ptrInImage points to, to where ptrTmpImage points to. The number of bytes is sizeof(IMAGE).

Comment: If you are new to pointers, I suggest you learn pointers.

Comment: @user253751 thanks fixed it!  
 memcpy(ptrTmpImage, ptrInImage, sizeof(IMAGE) + ptrInImage->size);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> c++, how to make a copy of the destination of a pointer

Simply indirect through the pointer and use that as the argument for copy initialisation of the other object. Example:

```
IMAGE *ptrInImage = ...
IMAGE copy = *ptrInImage;
```

Comment: This does not work in this case because I think the `IMAGE` is not what sharkyenregy wants to copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your example suggests `IMAGE` is an fixed-size object which precedes a variable-length `BYTE[]`. When you create a copy of just the `IMAGE` part, you don't copy the `BYTE[]`. And your example doesn't show how much bytes you have.

If you know that, you could call `operator new` with `sizeof(IMAGE)+bytelen`, call placement new to construct an `IMAGE` in the newly allocated memory, and then copy the remaining bytes. Possibly you'd want to update some `IMAGE` fields as well.